# Can't get the fully loaded html for a page using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to get the full html for [this page](http://www.electproject.org/2016g). It has a spreadsheet that loads slowly. I'm able to get the spreadsheet included when taking a screenshot of the page. However I can't get the *html* for the spreadsheet. `document.body.outerHTML` excludes the html for the spreadsheet. It's as if puppeteer is still seeing the page before the spreadsheet loads.

How do I get the fully loaded HTML including the HTML for the spreadsheet?

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("http://www.electproject.org/2016g", {
    timeout: 11000,
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 640,
    height: 880,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
  });
  await page.screenshot({ path: "buddy-screenshot.png", format: "A4" }); // this screenshot displays the spreadsheet
  let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.outerHTML); // this returns the html excluding the spreadsheet
  await browser.close();
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The spreadsheet is in an iframe, so you need to get the iframe first:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("http://www.electproject.org/2016g", {
    timeout: 11000,
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 640,
    height: 880,
    deviceScaleFactor: 1,
  });

  const spreadsheetFrame = page.frames().find(
    frame => frame.url().startsWith('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/')
  );

  let spreadsheetHead = await spreadsheetFrame.evaluate(
    () => document.body.querySelector('#top-bar').innerText
  );

  console.log(spreadsheetHead); // 2016 November General Election : Turnout Rates

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting me closer because I didn't realize it was an iframe. But it still just gets iframe without loading the spreadsheet data, same as before. I ended up just getting the spreadsheet directly. But I am still curious if it's possible to scrape the spreadsheet in the iframe without going to the linked spreadsheet.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait a bit more using `frame.waitForSelector()` or `frame.waitForFunction()`.